# how to parse the API response data using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got below data in API response

`{ secret: 'sn2MtJE1tDeESuuYcc7hBAJBGRABX', address: 'rwY9uCHHZkHTyns5Cwc5NHXLptkmNUs4Qv' }`

i want parse array format like below, Using php

```
array(secret=>sn2MtJE1tDeESuuYcc7hBAJBGRABX,address=>rwY9uCHHZkHTyns5Cwc5NHXLptkmNUs4Qv)
```

Comment: what you have tried to get this show your code?

Comment: validate you json here https://jsonlint.com/ not a valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = /* your json variable*/
$json = '{"secret":"sn2MtJE1tDeESuuYcc7hBAJBGRABX","address":"rwY9uCHHZkHTyns5Cwc5NHXLptkmNUs4Qv"}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($array);
```

> Array ( [secret] => sn2MtJE1tDeESuuYcc7hBAJBGRABX [address] => rwY9uCHHZkHTyns5Cwc5NHXLptkmNUs4Qv )

Comment: hey shanmugakumar s are you looking exactly above code